# Extract some lines with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, data-analysis

Hello I have this csv file :

```
Number;Name;Age
1;Pierre;10
2;Hugo;15
3;Albert;13
4;Vincent;16
5;Albert;10
```

And I would like with python and pandas to extract all the data which has the age of 10. How can I do this ? Thank you

I tried by this :

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter = ";")
```

Comment: `df[df.Age==10]`

Comment: That is not how I define "tried".

Comment: Thank you :) It works perfectly :)